# Angular in rails mounted engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

i wish to use angular in rails mounted engine. now what i added:

in master applications:

1. `ng-app` to the main html tag
2. `angular.js` file in `assets/javascript`

in the rails mounted engine:

1. `div ng-controller="Ctrl"` with `{{ title }}`
2. ```
   var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

     $scope.title = "42";

   });
   ```

now what i got is:

1. instead of `42` i see `{{title}}`
2. when i `console.log(angular)` i see its defined
3. if instead of `ng-app` in master application i use `angular.bootstrap` it doesn't work
4. if i do `angular.bootstrap` after 5 seconds, it works (tried document.ready, doesn't help)

now most how'tos i saw either were not complete or required a lot of dependencies and refactoring and i hope it can be done faster.

Comment: Do you add `ng-app="app"`? because you should define a name.

Comment: thanks, but that causes an Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]. i this error happens when using modules  you did not include, but i just used a simple {{var}}

Comment: Perhaps you should inject `$scope`: `.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.title = "42";

})];`

Comment: Also `'use strict';` at the start of js file is recommended by ng docs, but i don't think it affects.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: thanks, using var app = angular.module('app', []).controller(
 'Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { $scope.title = "42"; }]
 ); does not work, with our without adding "app" in ng-app="app"

Answer (score 2):

Use `$scope`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = "42";
}]);
```

Or you can inject `'$rootScope'`

in template:

```
 <body ng-app="app">
```

Comment: friend wait, i noted it doesnt work yet... using it "as is" prompts an error "Unexpected token )" so i changed closing to closing to "}]
 )" - no error- but doenst work

Comment: after changing to }]) no errors - but does not work as before. using rootscope also not...

Comment: Really strange. Don't know what else to recommend, do you have repository? Maybe i could notice something.

Comment: well, the git repository for entire project is company private, so cant, but we can maybe work around it: i can show your example to several people and maybe will get whats not working for us. anyways, thanks :)